# .Netstandard 2 library, send event on UI Thread

Tags: c#, uwp, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I have converted my library to .netstandard 2.

before converting the library i was able to execute this code to sync an event raised by the library with the UI thread

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    MyEvent.Invoke(param1, param2);
});
```

But converting the library this code rais an exception because is a platform specific code.

there is a way to solve this issue?

i have tried to use `MyEvent.BeginInvoke(param1, param2, null, null)`
but this raise a `platforn not supported exception` at runtime.

right now to solve this issue i'm synchronizing the event after is raised on the UI thread. UI Code:

```
internal async void MyEvent()
{
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        SomeCode......
    });
}
```

How can i sync the thread inside the library?

Comment: .NETStandard will never cater to UI implementation details.  MyEvents.BeginInvoke() does the complete opposite, it runs the delegate target on a TP thread.  And not implemented on .NETCore.  You ought to make Synchronization.Current work, copy it in the constructor and Post or Send to run code on the UI thread.  Works as long as it is code that runs on the UI thread that initializes the class.

Comment: Any time you try to get the `MainView`'s `CoreDispatcher` so you can invoke some code, it's a bug waiting to happen -- apps can have more than one view (or no views at all).